# MySQL: Update a full table, inserting a MD5 hash, for each row a specific one

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, md5

I added a column to an existing table. Now I need to update the tablecontent by adding a MD5 hash to that new column, based on the content of an existing column.

To be more precise:

```
id | name | date-of-birth | hash
1  | test | 12.12.12      | NULL
```

There are more than 1 million rows, where hash = NULL. Now I need to update hash with a MD5 string, that is bases on a corresponding column e.g. name:
hash = MD5(test)

I know how to do it for a single row. But how to do that for all rows in a single SQL Statement?

Comment: Sometimes it's quicker to google than to post a question... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET hash = MD5(name)
WHERE hash IS NULL
```

Note that the test is `hash IS NULL` and not `hash = NULL` as you wrote in your question.

Comment: here is my code : UPDATE users
SET reference_id = MD5(name.now())
WHERE reference_id IS NULL.
Error ! Function name doesn't exists

Comment: What's the performance of this query? Are there better ways? <Sorry for bumping this old thread>

Answer (score 0):

No need write an extra query for update.

- Just go to table design
- create a new column
- select new created column, below you'll get properties
- Find for computed Column Specification
- Under above opt you'll find formula section write HashBytes([Algo], [ColumnName])

it will automatically create an hash value for rows which are already present.

[Check the attached image for more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od3vm.png)